# Fetch result from function that returns table from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to fetch the result set from a function for each row of a parent result. Here is `table1`:

```
column
------
a1
a2
a3
a4
a5
```

I would like to loop through table1 and get the result of the function for each item in the column. The function returns a table.

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM functionReturnsTable(a.column))
FROM (SELECT column FROM table1) a
```

I have tried the query above however I get the error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How can I write a query/function that will loop through table1 and combine the result of each item into a single table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 AS a
CROSS APPLY dbo.functionReturnsTable(a.column) AS f;
```

Though you probably wouldn't use `SELECT *` in the production version, and you would probably always use schema prefix and statement terminators, right? :-)

Also, please stop thinking about this as a "loop"...

Comment: Based on your answer I'm using SELECT DISTINCT column, * at the moment. Let me try this out. Good point on the 'loop' mentality.